# Button in flex div cut in half

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a contact form, and I gave it's div `display:flex`.

All it's fields are being displayed correctly and dinamicaly resized, except for the submit button which is always cut in half.

Shouldn't it have the same behaviour has the rest of the fields?

Capture:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please show us the code, and have you assigned the property of `flex` to the child components of parent with `display:flex`?

Comment: I have no code to show, I'm using Divi with wordpress, the only think I've added was a `display:flex;` to the form itself as so: 
<br>
`form.et_pb_contact_form {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this.

```css
.child {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; border:1px solid black">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer to add a parent class to each controls, `select` fields might have some min-width that why button is shifting to left.